# Atomic vector error when using R package `stringr`

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, rvest

I want to use the packages `rvest` to pull gas prices from a web page. However, I can not pull the numeric values and have to pull by the html class `.sp_p`.

```
library(rvest)
desmoines <- html("http://www.desmoinesgasprices.com/")
```

Pull gas prices:

```
price <- desmoines %>%
  html_nodes(".sp_p")

head(price, 3)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
<div class="sp_p">
  <div class="p2"></div>
  <div class="pd"></div>
  <div class="p5"></div>
  <div class="p5"></div>
</div> 

[[2]]
<div class="sp_p">
  <div class="p2"></div>
  <div class="pd"></div>
  <div class="p5"></div>
  <div class="p6"></div>
</div> 

[[3]]
<div class="sp_p">
  <div class="p2"></div>
  <div class="pd"></div>
  <div class="p5"></div>
  <div class="p7"></div>
</div> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

Now, I want to use the package `stringr` to extract the digits from the web scrape, but I can't use `stringr` because `price` is not an atomic vector. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
library(stringr)
pr <- xml_children(price)
p_raw <- sapply(1:length(pr), function(x) paste(xml_attrs(pr[[x]]),collapse=""))
p_readable <- paste0("$",str_replace_all(p_raw,c("d"=".","p"="")))

#> p_readable
# [1] "$2.49" "$2.57" "$2.59" "$2.59" "$2.59" "$2.59" "$2.59" "$2.59" "$2.61" "$2.64" "$2.67" "$2.68" "$2.68"
#[14] "$2.68" "$3.08" "$2.99" "$2.98" "$2.98" "$2.98" "$2.98" "$2.98" "$2.98" "$2.98" "$2.98" "$2.98" "$2.98"
#[27] "$2.98" "$2.98" "$2.98"
```

Comment: I get `Error in vapply(list(...), length, integer(1)) : 
  argument "replacement" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Are you sure that you copy-pasted the code correctly? It's `sapply()`, not `vapply()`. I have no error message.

Comment: I'm using `rvest`version 0.2.0, `stringr` version 1.0.0, and `R` version 3.2.1.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I can help any further at the moment since I can't reproduce your error. Maybe somebody else can try and see what might be going wrong.

Comment: I updated `stringr` from 0.6.1 to 1.0.0 and everything worked perfectly. Thanks for your help